# Каким образом указать ссылку с пробелом и кирилицей?

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте указываю ссылку на скачивание в html на файл.

```
<a href="download/Файл номер, 1">Скачать</a>
```

но при клике в браузере, выдает ошибку.

```
Cannot GET /products/download/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%901-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3.xlsx
```

Если файл назван англ и без пробелов то всё работает нормально.

но мне нужно что бы они считывал на кирилице с пробелами и символами по возможности. так как файлов много, и каждый раз переименовывать не вариант. помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: яяя дико извиняюсь за вопрос, совсем забыл добавить файлы в DEST добавил их в SRC и думал ошибка в том что он не читает ссылку с кирилицей.

Comment: у вас этот файл в dest/products/download или в dest/download? и может не dest, а dist?

Answer (score 0):

Если сделать `decodeURI('%D0%90%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%901-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3')` то выведет
"Арматура-А1-круг", но я не вижу этого слова в ссылке, значит Вы переходите по ссылке `download/Файл номер, 1` и там оно пытается скачать уже арматуру, но по видимому оно не может найти эту арматуру для скачивания. Или Вы сократли ту большую ссылку к виду `download/Файл номер, 1`? Если да и она ведет на тот же файл что и указан в ошибке, то тогда просто нет такого файла.

**Попробуйте поменять**

```
<a href="download/Файл номер, 1">Скачать</a>
```

на

```
<a href="/download/Файл номер, 1">Скачать</a>
```

Если вы на странице products и вы нажимаете ссылку первого вида, то в ссылке есть префикс products, Вам он скорее таки и не нужен, у вас же файлы в `/download/`, не в `/products/download/`, правильно понимаю?